# Globals as function input instead arguments

Tags: python

I'm just learning about how Python works and after reading a while I'm still confused about globals and proper function arguments. Consider the case globals are not modified inside functions, only referenced.

Can globals be used instead function arguments? 
I've heard about using globals is considered a bad practice. Would it be so in this case?

Calling function without arguments:

```
def myfunc() :
    print myvalue

myvalue = 1
myfunc()
```

Calling function with arguments

```
def myfunc(arg) :
    print arg

myvalue = 1
myfunc(myvalue)
```

Comment: You can, but don't! Explicit is better than implicit. Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Comment: I would read this - http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html - it answers your question 100%

Comment: It should be a general principle, and not just in Python, that variables should be defined in the most restrictive scope possible.

Answer (score 2):

> I've heard about using globals is considered a bad practice. Would it be so in this case?

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. If `myfunc()` is supposed to print any value, then...

```
def myfunc(arg):
    print arg

myfunc(1)
```

...is better, but if `myfunc()` should always print the same value, then...

```
myvalue = 1

def myfunc():
    print myvalue

myfunc()
```

...is better, although with an example so simple, you may as well factor out the global, and just use...

```
def myfunc():
    print 1

myfunc()
```

Comment: well, if a function always returns the same thing it is questionable if it should be a function at all...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Making a variable `global` works in these cases instead of passing them in as a function argument. But, the problem is that as soon as you start writing bigger functions, you quickly run out of names and also it is hard to maintain the variables which are defined globally. If you don't need to edit your variable and only want to read it, there is no need to define it as `global` in the function.

Read about the cons of the global variables here - [Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Comment: Thank you Sukrit,

in fact, that's the case as I talked about above.
I am calling 'global' to any variable defined in the main code (don't know if this is right).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you need to change the value of a variable that is declared outside of the function then you can't pass it as an argument since that would create a "copy" of that variable inside the functions scope.
However if you only want to work with the value of a variable you should pass it as an argument. The advantage of this is that you can't mess up the global variable by accident.

Also you should declare global variable before they are used.

Comment: Sorry that I might not have explained it well...
My 'needs' are: 

-variables are ONLY defined in main code and never change.
-they are only read in functions and not edited at all.
-No 'global' declaration is neeed.

The question is why using globally defined variables instead of function arguments is considered a bad practice. I think Sukrit might be right when he says that problems arise when functions grow bigger....

Comment: If those values nevery change then it's not bad practice to define them once on the start of the script and then simply acces them inside functions. usually such constants are bound to all upper case names e.g. IP = "10.122.10.12"

Comment: @Mike -- pypat is right - if you have basic constants declared at the start of you program and they never change, it is ok to use them. But they should be written in uppercase, so there is a clear distinction from all other variables. If they change even once throughout the program you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why using function arguments is better than using globals:

1. It eliminates possible confusion: once your program gets large, it will become really hard to keep track of which global is used where. Passing function arguments lets you be much more clear about which values the function uses.
2. There's a particular mistake you WILL make eventually if you use globals, which will look *very* strange until you understand what's going on. It has to do with both modifying and reading a global variable in the same function. More on this later.
3. Global variables all live in the same namespace, so you will quickly run into the problem of overlapping names. What if you want two different variables named "index"? Calling them `index1` and `index2` is going to get real confusing, real fast. Using local variables, or function parameters, means that they all live in different namespaces, and the potential for confusion is greatly reduced.

Now, I mentioned modifying and reading a global variable in the same function, and a confusing error that can result. Here's what it looks like:

```
record_count = 0  # Global variable
def func():
    print "Record count:", record_count
    # Do something, maybe read a record from a database
    record_count = record_count + 1  # Would normally use += 1 here, but it's easier to see what's happening with the "n = n + 1" syntax
```

This will FAIL: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'record_count' referenced before assignment`

Wait, what? Why is `record_count` being treated as a local variable, when it's clearly global? Well, if you never *assigned* to `record_count` in your function, then Python would use the global variable. But when you assign a value to `record_count`, Python has to guess what you mean: whether you want to modify the global variable, or whether you want to create a new local variable that shadows (hides) the global variable, and deal only with the local variable. And Python will default to assume that you're being smart with globals (i.e., not modifying them without knowing *exactly* what you're doing and why), and assume that you meant to create a new local variable named `record_count`.

But if you're accessing a local variable named `record_count` inside your function, Python won't let you access the global variable with the same name inside the function. This is to spare you some really *nasty*, hard-to-track-down bugs. Which means that if this function has a *local* variable named `record_count` -- and it does, because of the assignment statement -- then *all* access to `record_count` is considered to be accessing the local variable. **Including** the access in the `print` statement, before the local variable's value is defined. Thus, the `UnboundLocalError` exception.

Now, an exercise for the reader. Remove the print statement and notice that the `UnboundLocalError` exception is *still* thrown. Can you figure out why? (Hint: before assigning to a variable, the value on the right-hand side of the assignment has to be calculated.)

Now: if you *really* want to use the global `record_count` variable in your function, the way to do it is with Python's `global` statement, which says "Hey, this variable name I'm about to specify? Don't ever make it a local variable, even if I assign to it. Assign to the global variable instead." The way it works is just `global record_count` (or any other variable name), at the start of your function. Thus:

```
record_count = 0  # Global variable
def func():
    global record_count
    print "Record count:", record_count
    # Do something, maybe read a record from a database
    record_count = record_count + 1  # Again, you would normally use += 1 here
```

This will do what you expected in the first place. But hopefully now you understand *why* it will work, and the other version won't.